# Android: asking to add additional or optional raw files after application downloaded market

Tags: android, resources, apk

I will try to add external resources to my apk. But firstly, I have to ask that is it possible

For example, one downloaded my app from google market, when app launches, I get his/her default language and ask to "do you want to download additional mp3 files?". If he/she presses "ok", my app download additional resources and starts.

I have to do that because I'm using mp3 files in my application. These files expand application size much more. Besides, my application supports a lot of different language, I can not add all my mp3 files initially. That was not useful.

Additionally, I know and use localization (values/ values-fr/ values-es/ values-) for strings. String files don't expand my application size much more, those are not important, however mp3 files(raw file) are crucial.

Are there anybody that knows how can I realize that?

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U need server to contain data "mp3 files" and if user accept ur request i think u must donwload it with json or what ever else. Also u need to request permissions on M android.

Comment: Request permissions? What for?

Comment: Check permission for read/ save external storage. Also record audio needs permissions

Comment: Yes im right https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous